# If $p,q$ are primes, then there are only two groups of size $pq$ up to an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $p,q$ be primes. Show there are exactly two groups of order $pq$, up to an isomorphism
>
> $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_q\simeq\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$

I am not too sure what this question is asking or if it even makes sense. I am rather new to group theory, and would appreciate it if someone could guide me through this problem, or direct me to the actual question incase the above makes no sense.

I did some research and it has to do with something regarding the Sylow Theorem's. The above "$\times$" indicates a direct product. I am however, not familiar with semi-direct products.

I apologize regarding the ambiguity of the question and the lack of work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2650258/255913

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the second line of the problem you quote is intended to mean; it is not really part of the problem. It could be some kind of a hint. The question ask to show that there are only two types of groups of the order $pq$. One of them is the one you quote. There is another one. And yes IIRC Sylow is useful there.

Answer (score 4):

If $p=q$, there are two groups of order $p^2$, namely $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$. If $p,q$ are distinct primes, suppose $p<q$. Then there are two cases.

If $p$ does not divide $q-1$, then the only group of order $pq$ is the cyclic one. The assumption $p$ does not divide $q-1$ in conjunction with Sylow's theorems allows one to conclude that there are *unique* subgroups of order $p$ and $q$ respectively. The union of these two subgroups has cardinality $p+q-1$, and since $p+q-1<pq$ you can obtain an element of order $pq$ in the ambient group.

If $p$ does divide $q-1$, then we have two groups: in addition to the cyclic group of order $pq$, there is also going to be (up to isomorphism) one unique *non-abelian* (indeed, centreless) group of order $pq$, which can be obtained using semi-direct products. An example of this is $S_3$, which is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thank you for your answer. Would there be any way to show this rigorously without using semi-direct products?